# What is the formula for Legendre Polynomials from EGM96 calculated in F447.f program?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, gravity, mathematics

[The F447.f program](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm96/f477.f) is designed to calculate the geoid undulation for EGM96.
I'm trying to understand how it accomplish this calculation. 
I stuck in `SUBROUTINE LEGFDN`. I want to understand what is the formula for `RLNN(N)` vector. So far I'm sure only for `RLNN(1)=1`.

I believe `RLNN(2) = SITHET*DRTS(3) = sen(theta)*sqrt(3)`, 
but I don't understanding `RLNN(3)` and forward.

The loop below can be translated

```
      DO 15  N1 = 3,M1
      N = N1-1
      N2 = 2*N
   15 RLNN(N1) = DRTS(N2+1)*DIRT(N2)*SITHET*RLNN(N1-1)
```

to something like this

```
      DO 15  N = 2,M
      RLNN(N+1)=SQRT(2*N+1)*1/SQRT(2*N)*SIN(THETA)*RLNN(N)
  15  END DO
```

where M=360 is the polynomial degree and THETA (I believe) is the latitude, someone recognize this recursion formula as part of some Legendre polynomial?

Comment: I am happy to see FORTRAN code!  All the GO TOs, not so much.

Comment: Are those non-standard Legendre polynomials?

Comment: ANCIENT, ALL CAPS FORTRAN code. It's nigh impossible to read. LAWYERS USE ALL CAPS TO RENDER KEY PARTS OF A LEGAL DOCUMENT UNREADABLE. There is no reason to emulate such behavior.

Comment: @DavidHammen what are these "lower case characters" of which you speak? :) https://live.staticflickr.com/195/522484762_a2cc146805_b.jpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a recurrence for a Legendre polynomial $P_{n}(\mu)$
but an Associated Legendre Function (ALF).
This[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials) states much more than is needed here.

ALFs are often denoted $P_{n,m}(\mu)$
in geophysics.
The degree $n$ and order $m$ are non-negative integers
$0, 1, 2, \dots$ with $0 \le m \le n.$
Argument $\mu$ is the sine of the latitude
(measured north or south from the equator),
or equivalently the cosine of the colatitude
(measured southward from the north pole).

ALFs appear as factors in solid spherical harmonic formulas.
Such formulas are used to represent a gravitational field.
Spherical harmonics are classified
as zonal, sectorial, or tesseral
according to whether $m=0$ (zonal),
$m=n$ (sectorial),
or $0 < m < n$ (tesseral).
Applying those conventions to ALFs,
zonals are the same as Legendre polynomials:
$P_{n,0}(\mu) = P_{n}(\mu).$
Sectorials correspond to $P_{n,n}(\mu),$
while $P_{n,m}(\mu), \, 0 < m < n$ correspond to tesserals.

An ALF might evaluate to a very large
numeric value for large $n$ or $m$.
Geophysicists often introduce a normalization factor
which I denote $N_{n,m}$.  Its formula is
\begin{align*}
N_{n,m} = \begin{cases}
  \sqrt {(2n+1) \dfrac  {(n-m)!}{(n+m)!}}, & m = 0
  \\
  \sqrt {2 (2n+1) \dfrac  {(n-m)!}{(n+m)!}}, & m > 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
A "fully normalized" ALF 
using $N_{n,m}$
is indicated by a bar above the $P$:
\begin{align*}
  \overline{P}_{n,m}(\mu) = N_{n,m} \, P_{n,m}(\mu)
  \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
  P_{n,m}(\mu) = \overline{P}_{n,m}(\mu) / N_{n,m}
  .
\end{align*}

A sectorial recurrence using colatitude $\theta$ is
\begin{align*}
P_{n,n}(\cos \theta) = (2n-1) \sin \theta \; P_{n-1,n-1}(\cos \theta)
\end{align*}
beginning with $P_{0,0} = 1$ by definition
and $P_{1,1} = \sin \theta$ by the recurrence.
(Note that the ALF argument is $\cos \theta$
but that $\sin \theta$ appears as a factor in the RHS.)
This recurrence can be expressed using fully normalized ALFs
by substituting $P_{n,n}(\mu) = \overline{P}_{n,n}(\mu) / N_{n,n}$.  Assume $n > 1$:
\begin{align*}
  \frac {\overline{P}_{n,n}(\cos \theta)} {N_{n,n}}
& = 
  (2n-1) \sin \theta \;
  \frac {\overline{P}_{n-1,n-1}(\cos \theta)} {N_{n-1,n-1}}
\\ 
  \frac {\overline{P}_{n,n}(\cos \theta)} 
        {\sqrt{2 (2n+1) \dfrac {0!} {(2n)!}}}
& = 
  (2n-1) \sin \theta \;
  \frac {\overline{P}_{n-1,n-1}(\cos \theta)} 
        {\sqrt{2 (2n-1) \dfrac {0!} {(2n-2)!}}}
\\ 
  \overline{P}_{n,n}(\cos \theta)
& = 
  \sqrt{\dfrac {2 (2n+1) } {(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)!}}
  (2n-1)
  \sqrt {\frac {(2n-2)!} {2(2n-1)}
    } 
  \sin \theta \;
  \overline{P}_{n-1,n-1}(\cos \theta)
\\ 
& = 
  \sqrt{ \dfrac {2n+1} {2n}}
  \sin \theta \;
  \overline{P}_{n-1,n-1}(\cos \theta)
.
\end{align*}
This corresponds to the OP's code fragment,
with the convention that $\overline{P}_{n,n}$
is stored in RLNN(N+1).

Comment: Exemplary answer! It's great when someone takes the time to wade through some complicated math and bring it to a successful resolution, and do some helpful teaching in the process. `+1` Any thoughts on [How can I verify my reconstructed gravity field of Ceres from spherical harmonics?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27779/12102) they would be

Comment: So the ALF are simplified forms of Legendre polynomials and can be used instead of them in the appropriated framework?

Comment: I wouldn't say ALFs are simplified; if anything, they are more complicated because they are more general.  Legendre polynomials (the m=0 case of ALFs) are associated only with zonal terms.  ALFs are associated with sectorial and tesseral terms.  All three sets are needed to represent a gravitational field using solid spherical harmonics.

Comment: @uhoh I agree with ChrisR's answer to your [linked question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27779/how-can-i-verify-my-reconstructed-gravity-field-of-ceres-from-spherical-harmonic) -- validation is tough without someone else's results.  What I could show is recurrences for Pnm, fullly normalized and not.  Would that help?

Comment: @BobWerner Hmm... At the time, the only "someone else's result" I'd found was the Bouguer anomaly map I'd included in the question. That my maps truncated at n=4 and 5 don't look even a little bit like it may mean simply that I didn't know what I was doing. Why don't I have another look at each 1) my question 2) the literature and 3) ChrisR's answer first. In the mean time, I wonder if "recurrences for Pnm, fullly normalized and not" might be helpful for [How are the coefficients in the EGM96 model normalized?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12617/12102)

Comment: @BobWerner okay, reading up on [Bouguer anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouguer_anomaly) there's no reason to expect them to be similar, and a reference surface would probably be necessary to try to match them up. I'd better do some more "homework" on this.

Answer (score 3):

(This answer continues the one above.)

A table of $P_{n,m}(\mu)$ values
can be envisioned as a square array.
Rows down the page are indexed by degree $n$,
and columns to the right by order $m$.

Due to the underlying math, 
the only sensible $P_{n,m}(\mu)$ values occur for
$0 \le m \le n$.
The effect is that the table is lower-triangular
instead of square;
$P_{n,m}(\mu)$ do not exist above the $m=n$ diagonal.

Values along the $m=n$ diagonal correspond to the 
sectorial terms described in 
the preceding answer.
A simple recurrence provides the value of
$P_{n,n}(\mu)$ from the preceding value $P_{n-1,n-1}(\mu)$.

A different recurrence provides values down a column.
This "vertical" recurrence uses the two immediately preceding values
higher in the column.
For example in column $m=3$,
the value of $P_{6,3}(\mu)$ can be computed
from $P_{5,3}(\mu)$ and $P_{4,3}(\mu)$.

The vertical recurrence using colatitude $\theta$ is:
\begin{align*}
  (n-m) P_{n,m}(\cos\theta) 
= (2n-1) \cos\theta \; P_{n-1,m} (\sin\theta) - (n-m-1) P_{n-2,m}(\cos\theta)
\end{align*}
This recurrence using unnormalized $P_{n,m}(\cos\theta)$ 
can be converted to 
fully normalized $\overline{P}_{n,m}(\cos\theta)$
in the same way as used above for converting the sectorial recurrence:
$\overline{P}_{n,m}(\cos\theta) / N_{n,m}$ is substituted for $P_{n,m}(\cos\theta)$.
\begin{align*}
\overline{P}_{n,m}(\cos\theta)
& = 
  \frac {N_{n,m}}
        {n-m}
  \left[
    \frac {2n-1} 
          {N_{n-1,m}}
     \cos\theta \; \overline{P}_{n-1,m} (\cos\theta)
    - \frac {n+m-1}
            {N_{n-2,m}}
    \overline{P}_{n-2,m}(\cos\theta)
  \right]
\\ & =
  \frac {\sqrt{(2-\delta_{0,m}) (2n+1) \frac{(n-m)!}{(n+m)!}}}
        {n-m}
  \left[ \begin{array}{l}
    \dfrac {2n-1} 
           {\sqrt{(2-\delta_{0,m}) (2n-1) \frac{(n-m-1)!} {(n+m-1)!}}}
     \cos\theta \; \overline{P}_{n-1,m} (\cos\theta)
  \\ \quad
    - \dfrac {n+m-1}
             {\sqrt{(2-\delta_{0,m}) (2n-3) \frac{(n-m-2)!} {(n+m-2)!}}}
    \overline{P}_{n-2,m}(\cos\theta)
  \end{array} \right]
\\ & =
  \frac {\sqrt{(2n+1) \frac{(n-m)(n-m-1)(n-m-2)!}{(n+m)(n+m-1)(n+m-2)!}}}
        {n-m}
  \left[ \begin{array}{l}
    \dfrac {2n-1} 
           {\sqrt{(2n-1) \frac{(n-m-1)(n-m-2)!} {(n+m-1)(n+m-2)!}}}
     \cos\theta \; \overline{P}_{n-1,m} (\cos\theta)
  \\ \quad
    - \dfrac {n+m-1}
             {\sqrt{(2n-3) \frac{(n-m-2)!} {(n+m-2)!}}}
    \overline{P}_{n-2,m}(\cos\theta)
  \end{array} \right]
\\ & =
  \frac {\sqrt{(2n+1) \frac{(n-m)(n-m-1)}{(n+m)(n+m-1)}}}
        {n-m}
  \left[ \begin{array}{l}
    \dfrac {2n-1} 
           {\sqrt{(2n-1) \frac{(n-m-1)} {(n+m-1)}}}
     \cos\theta \; \overline{P}_{n-1,m} (\cos\theta)
  \\ \quad
    - \dfrac {n+m-1}
             {\sqrt{2n-3}}
    \overline{P}_{n-2,m}(\cos\theta)
  \end{array} \right]
\\ & =
  \sqrt{\frac{2n+1} {(n-m)(n+m)}} 
  \sqrt{\frac{n-m-1}{n+m-1}}
  \left[ \begin{array}{l}
    \sqrt{(2n-1) \frac{n+m-1} {n-m-1}}
     \cos\theta \; \overline{P}_{n-1,m} (\cos\theta)
  \\ \quad
    - \dfrac {n+m-1}
             {\sqrt{2n-3}}
    \overline{P}_{n-2,m}(\cos\theta)
  \end{array} \right]
\\ & =
  \sqrt{\frac{2n+1} {(n-m)(n+m)}} 
  \left[ \begin{array}{l}
    \sqrt{2n-1}
     \cos\theta \; \overline{P}_{n-1,m} (\cos\theta)
  \\ \quad
    - \sqrt{
      \dfrac {(n-m-1)(n+m-1)}
             {2n-3}
      }
    \overline{P}_{n-2,m}(\cos\theta)
  \end{array} \right]
.
\end{align*}
This is the vertical recurrence 
for fully normalized $\overline{P}_{n,m}(\cos\theta)$.

One wrinkle is that
when computing the subdiagonal term
$\overline{P}_{n+1,n}(\cos\theta)$,
there is only one preceding term 
(the diagonal $\overline{P}_{n,n}(\cos\theta)$).
The second preceding term (above the diagonal) does not exist.
In this special case, 
only the first term within the brackets is needed.

[F447.f program](https://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm96/f477.f)

The subroutine
LEGFDN
saves values of $\sqrt {i}$ in array 
DRTS(i)
and the reciprocal $1 / \sqrt {i}$ in
DIRT(i).
The subroutine's code

```
      RLEG(N1) = DRTS(N2+1)*DIRT(N+M)*DIRT(N-M)*(DRTS(N2-1)*COTHET*  
     2 RLEG(N1-1)-DRTS(N+M-1)*DRTS(N-M-1)*DIRT(N2-3)*RLEG(N1-2))
```

near the bottom of DO-loop 30 is equivalent to

```
      RLEG(N1) = SQRT(2*N+1)/SQRT(N+M)/SQRT(N-M)*
     1 ( SQRT(2*N-1)*COS(THETA)*RLEG(N1-1)
     2 - SQRT(N+M-1)*SQRT(N-M-1)/SQRT(2*N-3)*RLEG(N1-2)
     3 )
```

This corresponds exactly to the
vertical recurrence.
Evidently $\overline{P}_{n,m}(\cos\theta)$ is
stored in one-dimensional array 
RLEG(n).
(I've not studied the code to understand how it handles 
the various columns.)

One conclusion is that the 
normalization formula used in 
the F447.f program
is the $N_{n,m}$ formula given in the preceding answer.